# React Transition Group

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I have been reading about React Transition Group.  95% of the material talks about CSSTransitionGroup.  My understanding is that CSSTransitionGroup just builds off of TransitionGroup which simply provides callback methods that correspond to various animation events.

So I've wrapped my component up in a TransitionGroup element and given it an animation event but it is never fired.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { TransitionGroup, Transition } from "react-transition-group";



class Test extends Component {


    componentWillAppear(cb) {
        console.log('componentWillAppear')
        cb()
    }

    render() {
        return <div> test </div>
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <TransitionGroup>
         <Test />
         </TransitionGroup>
         )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what version of `react-transition-group` are you using?

Comment: i'm away from my computer now but i just npm'd the package name without specifying anything exact.

Comment: In the latest version, `TransitionGroup` is not the base of `CSSTransition`.  There is a base called `Transition`: https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by 'base of'.  i've read that article at least 5 times and cannot make sense of it.  every article i've read has been wildly out of agreement with each other.  do i need to use transitionGroup + transition.  or can I use either alone?  is there additional reading or examples that can make any of this clear?

Comment: Sorry, yeah `base` is a bit of an overloaded term.  I think @Max's answer is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Transition` or `CSSTransition` without `TransitionGroup`, but you can't use `TransitionGroup` without one of the others.

From the react-transition-group [docs](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/#TransitionGroup):

> The `<TransitionGroup>` component manages a set of `<Transition>` components in a list. Like with the `<Transition>` component, `<TransitionGroup>`, is a state machine for managing the mounting and unmounting of components over time.
>
> ...As items are removed or added to the TodoList the in prop is toggled automatically by the `<TransitionGroup>`.

Try changing your Test component's render to something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Transition timeout={150}>
            {(status) => (
                <div className={`fade fade-${status}`}>
                    test
                <div>
            )}
        </Transition>
    )
}
```

Comment: i only get `entered` or `exited` states.  not `entering` or `exiting` even with the timeout.

Comment: also from my reading of the docs, you should be able to use TransitionGroup alone. `ReactTransitionGroup is the basis for animations. When children are declaratively added or removed from it (as in the example above), special lifecycle hooks are called on them.`

Comment: Try putting a `console.log(state)` inside the Transition, before the return.

Comment: it seems that you need to set the `in` prop for a `Transition` component.

Comment: You need the `in`, but even if parents re-render I only get entered state of the transition :o(